# Downloading YouTube videoes with pafy module with tqdm progressbar

Tags: python, youtube, tqdm, pafy

I am trying to make a code to download videos from YouTube using `pafy` module and a progressbar using `tqdm` module, however the progressbar is finished before the download complete.

here is my code download piece:

```
with tqdm.tqdm(desc=video_name, total=video_size, unit_scale=True, unit='B', initial=0) as pbar:
     bestVideo.download(filepath=full_path, quiet=True, callback=lambda _, received, *args: pbar.update(received))
```

here is  a pic a the progressbar:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMBUN.png

Comment: how do you get `video_size`? Is it correct value - do you get downloaded file with the same size?

Comment: I get `video_size` correctly and the downloaded file is working when downloading complete, the only probleme is the progressbar finishes before download complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is because `pbar.update()` expects value `current_received - previous_received`

`download` gives only `current_received` so you have to use some variable to rember previous value and substract it

---

Minimal working code:

```
import pafy
import tqdm

# --- functions ---

previous_received = 0

def update(pbar, current_received):
    global previous_received
    
    diff = current_received - previous_received
    pbar.update(diff)
    previous_received = current_received

# --- main ---

v = pafy.new("cyMHZVT91Dw")
s = v.getbest()

video_size = s.get_filesize()
print("Size is", video_size)
    
with tqdm.tqdm(desc="cyMHZVT91Dw", total=video_size, unit_scale=True, unit='B', initial=0) as pbar:
     s.download(quiet=True, callback=lambda _, received, *args:update(pbar, received))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine... I was gonna use `requests` module instead but this is easier